# Find document with PouchDB and Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I have two pages: home.ts and stade.ts

I've created all my documents with PouchDb in a home.ts page in Ionic 3 and added some data.

I wish to get documents already created in home.ts but in the stade.ts page.

```
       this.db.get(187).then(function (doc) {
          // handle doc
          }).catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

When I load this stade.ts page, I have this kind of error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Comment: May be i need to create a provider in Ionic and call it to the stades.ts page's constructor

Comment: Yes you should create a provider/service and make it have setter and getter methods. Then import/dependency inject this provider to the pages you need and work with it this way.